# Why does .all? return true on an empty array?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby I want to evaluate all items in an array, and return true if they all pass a conditional test.

I can do this using e.g. `array.all? { |value| value == 2 }`

So:

```
> array=[2,2]
> array.all? { |value| value == 2 }
=> true
> array=[2,3]
> array.all? { |value| value == 2 }
=> false
```

Great!

But, why does an empty array pass this test?

```
> array=[]
> array.all? { |value| value == 2 }
=> true
```

Shouldn't this return false?

And if I need it to return false, how should I modify the method?

Comment: Why should it return false?

Comment: This is a [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).  It's the standard interpretation of a universal quantification (i.e. a `all? { |x| some_predicate(x) }`) over an empty set, but it's known to strike people as counter-intuitive when they first see it in a formal setting.  One nice way to think about why this is the preferred semantics is to think about how you would implement `all?`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby you can never loop over an empty collection (array, hashes, etc.), so in your case your block never gets executed.  And if the block never gets executed, `all?` returns true (there is no condition to make the result false).

Read about `all?` in [the Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

You can simply achieve your goal by

```
  !array.empty? && array.all? { |value| value == 2 }
```

Comment: many good answers here. I've marked this one as the chosen answer because it clearly explains the issue, refers and links to the documentation, and provides a solution.

Comment: in Ruby >= 1.8.6 you can use 
`array.any?`
instead of `!array.empty?`
to avoid double negative

Answer (score 33):

This is a [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). It's the standard interpretation of a universal quantification, i.e. a

```
collection.all? { |x| some_predicate(x) }
```

over an empty `collection`, but it's known to strike people as counter-intuitive when they first see it in a formal setting. One nice way to think about why this is the preferred semantics is to think about how you would implement `all?`.

To make your test require that the array is non-empty, just do

```
array.any? && array.all? { |x| x == 2 }
```

Note that `array.any?` is fast no matter how large the array, whereas `array.all? { |x| x == 2 }` can be slow, depending on how big `array` is and how rare `2` is in it.  So put the `array.any?` first.

Also note, there are degenerate cases where this won't work, for instance if `array` is `[nil]` or `[false]`.  If cases like this might come up, replace `array.any?` with `array.any? { true }`.

Comment: `array.any? && array.all? { |x| x == 2 }` in this line - I didn't catch your point to suggest to use `all?` and `any?` both. Could you help me to understand the same?

Comment: i also wonder why use `any?` and not `!.empty?` given your comment on degenerate cases. Please explain

Comment: Yes, +1, this is the most correct explanation of the core team reasoning when designing the method. And @sawa can notice, that in the Wiki article linked by this answer, there is no absolute consensus on when vacuously true statements should be regarded as "really" true, and when as exceptional.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation says : "*The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil..*"
In the case of an empty array the block never executes and hence the method will always return `true`. As far as returning `false` is concerned you'll have to `arr.empty?`

Comment: `As far as returning false is concerned you'll have to arr.empty?` didn't get the meaning of your line. Could you help me to understand this?

Comment: @Priti : apologies, should have elaborated - `arr.empty? ? false : array.all? { |value| value == 2 }` or something or that sort!

Answer (score 4):

There is no item in that array that doesn't pass the test. I think you may need to throw in a test for array length.

Answer (score 1):

Just go

```
!(array.empty? || array.any? {|x| x != 2})
```

(Which has the added advantage of failing fast—that is, it can be evaluated properly without having to scan the whole array.)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no item in the array that FAILS that test, it returns true. So just use somehting like:

```
array.size > 0 and array.all? { |value| value == 2}
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Zeroes, empty collections, empty matrices and such have always been a bit special, if not outright problematic. Greeks knew well why they didn't count 0 among natural integers.

Method `all?` would be the first to ask *you* "why are you calling me on an empty array?" What do you mean by "all?", when there is nothing in there? That's a contradiction. And the method does short thinking, and answers `true` for the reasons outlined in the other three answers. Remember, you are at fault for talking about "all elements" of an empty array to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As Amit Kumar Gupta writes, it is the standard interpretation of universal quantification. I have no idea why you expect it to be `false`. Here, you can see it should be `true` by inference.

---

Universal quantification is equivalent to conjunction, thus ("<=>" means equivalent):

```
"for all x in [a, b, c], P(x)" <=> "P(a) and P(b) and P(c)"
```

Notice that any proposition is equivalent to the conjunction of true and itself, so:

```
"for all x in [a, b, c], P(x)" <=> "true and P(a) and P(b) and P(c)"
```

If you lessen the elements in the set to two, you get:

```
"for all x in [a, b], P(x)" <=> "true and P(a) and P(b)"
```

and further to one element:

```
"for all x in [a], P(x)" <=> "true and P(a)"
```

Now, what happens with the empty set? Naturally,

```
"for all x in [], P(x)" <=> "true"
```

---

By noticing that existential quantification is equivalent to disjunction, you can also see that you should expect `false` with existential quantification over an empty set.

Comment: I didn't understand your line - `"for all x in [a, b, c], P(x)" <=> "true and P(a) and P(b) and P(c)"`. could you help me to understand this?

Comment: Uh oh, your mathematics is too hermetic for me. The magic happens when you progress from `true and P(a)` to `true` :-)))). Properly, you should go from `true and P(a, b)` --> `true and P(a)` --> `true and P()` and the problem stands unresolved :-)))

Comment: @Priti: In math, `<=>` is not Ruby three way comparison, but means _if and only if_, just like `=>` is not Ruby rocket, but means _implication_.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky What do you mean by `P(a, b)`? This is supposed to iterate over `x` one at a time, so there shouldn't be any proposition taking both `a` and `b` at a time. Regarding associativity of conjunction, I took it for granted.

Comment: @sawa: I'm not saying that the choice of `all?` doing things the way it does is wrong, I'm just saying that your explanation does not constitue a formal reason for such behavior.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky It is a matter of definition. When a definition is to be extended, the only way is to infer from other cases and try to make it fit as naturally as possible. That is what I showed. And what is `P(a, b)`? You didn't answer.

Comment: @sawa: What I refer to as `P(a, b)` is what you refer to as `P(a) and P(b)`. In my case, that would be `def P( *args ); args.empty? ? FOOBAR : args.reduce { |accumulator, arg| accumulator and arg.call } end`, a function with variable number of arguments, which all must be nullary closures closed over the calls of the block passed to `all?` method with each of the individual elements of the collection, that is the receiver of the `all?` method in question, if I must be explicit. Constant `FOOBAR` then defines the value to return if the collection is empty, and there is no obvious choice for it.

Comment: @sava: Continuing, there is no self-evident or formally inferrable choice for what `all?` method should do when its receiver is empty. It currently returns `true`, by the decision of the Ruby core team, but it coud as well return `nil`, like `reduce` does when no seed value is injected, or it could raise `TypeError` with some witty message, or some other exception, or it could do something completely else, such as `throw` symbol `:reduce_over_empty_collection` and ask of you to catch it. Good or bad, these all are the possibilities. The only good answer to the OP is "because Matz decided so".

Comment: You are introducing a special conditional for empty cases within your definition of `P(*args)`. Why do you do that? That looks arbitrary. It is not a natural extension.

Comment: As for your opinion that it could be undefined for empty cases, that makes sense because that is the way natural languages work. There is a consensus among linguists that there is a presupposition that the set to be iterated over in quantification (called restrictor) not be empty. If the presupposition is not satisfied, then the expression is invalid. In programming languages, that would correspond to an argument/type error; or in Ruby, that might correspond to `nil`. However, there is no rationare for expecting a `false` value.

Answer (score 0):

The source of all? method says that it uses static variable(which is initially set to true) and then performs the AND operation between the static variable value and the result of the iteration finally returns this static variable as a result.

as the array is Empty ruby will never iterate on this empty array and as a result of this all? method will return the static variable which was set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the array is not empty first. 
Then:

```
array.compact.present? && array.all? {|x| x != 2}
```