# Why any('') returns logical 0 while all('') returns logical 1?

Tags: matlab

I just found the statement `any('')` returns a **logical 0**, while the statement `all('')` returns a **logical 1**.

If the function `any` does not think the empty string ('') as nonzero, the function `all` should do the same, but from the result, the function `all` seems to think the empty string ('') as nonzero.

BTW, the similar thing happens where `any(NaN)` returns logical 0 while `all(NaN)` returns logical 1.

Is it a MATLAB bug?

Here is the version information of the MATLAB I am using.
MATLAB Version: 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)
MATLAB License Number: DEMO

Comment: Maybe add it to the list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710299/corner-cases-unexpected-and-unusual-matlab?rq=1

Comment: It’s not a bug. any(X) means you can find an element of X that is true; for no elements, you can’t. all(X) means you can’t find an element of X that is false; for no elements, you can’t. Compare ∀, ∃, and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195289/why-does-iqueryable-all-return-true-on-an-empty-collection, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223079/why-does-stream-allmatch-return-true-for-an-empty-stream, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601802/how-does-all-in-python-work-on-empty-lists, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662727/why-does-all-return-true-on-an-empty-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solid proof from the documentation about the `any` and `all` functions, as follows.

**Documentation of the function `any`**
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html

> If A is an empty 0-by-0 matrix, any(A) returns logical 0 (false).

**Documentation of the function `all`**
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html

> If A is an empty 0-by-0 matrix, then all(A) returns logical 1 (true).

And **the empty string in MATLAB is actually a 0×0 empty char array** (I just found it). That explains my original question, from the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Documentation
definition of [any](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html):

> any(x) ...determines if any element is a *nonzero number* or logical 1 (true)
>
> In practice, `any` is a natural extension of the logical OR operator.
>
> If A is an empty 0-by-0 matrix, `any(A)` returns logical 0 (false).

and definition of [all](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html):

> all(x) ...determines if the elements are all *nonzero* or logical 1 (true)
>
> In practice, `all` is a natural extension of the logical AND operator.
>
> If A is an empty 0-by-0 matrix, then `all(A)` returns logical 1 (true).

We can implement both functions:

```
function out = Any(V)
    out = false;
    for k = 1:numel(V)
        out = out || (~isnan(V(k)) && V(k) ~= 0);
    end
end

function out = All(V)
    out = true;
    for k = 1:numel(V)
        out = out && (V(k) ~= 0);
    end
end
```

Explanation:

-In `any` we assume that all elements are not nonzero [so all are zeros] and we want to prove that the assumption is wrong so we provide an initial value of `false`.
-Because `any` is a natural extension of the logical OR operator we use `||`
-Because we should check for `nonzero` numbers we use `V(k) ~= 0`
-Because we should check for nonzeros `numbers` and `NaN` is `Not a Number` we use `~isnan(V(k))`.

-In `all` we assume that all elements are nonzero [so all are ones] and we want to prove that the assumption is wrong so we provide an initial value of `true`
-Because `all` is a natural extension of the logical AND operator we use `&&`
-Because we should check for nonzeros we use `V(k) ~= 0`
-Because  the definition of `all`  doesn't force that nonzero elements to be numbers we don't use `~isnan(V(k))`

Comment: Thanks for so detailed reply. I think I understand your explanation. I also double checked the documentation (indeed, the `any` function ignores NaN values while the `all` function doesn't mention it) and run the 2 functions provided by you, and the results prove your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Any returns 0 because it is not the case that any of its elements are true. An `any` clause is true if any of its elements are true.

All returns 1 because it is the case that all of its elements are true. All of its elements are true so long as none of its elements are false, and none of its elements are false.

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient and consistent w.r.t the rest of your math when applying an *associative operation* over an empty list of values returns the *neutral element* of that operation. This is why

- a sum of zero numbers is 0
- a product of zero numbers is 1
- a logical or of zero booleans is false
- a logical and of zero booleans is true

Keywords for further reading: monoid, fold.